# Passando uma variável dentro de uma procedure

Tags: delphi, loop, procedure

tenho essa procedure no meu projeto

```
procedure DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant);
```

Agora preciso usar ela em um loop passando a variável de contagem. Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
procedure DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant; var contagem : Integer);
```

Mas acontece que quando vou passar a variável, a procedure pede também os outros parâmetros `Sender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL: OleVariant` que, cá entre nós, não faço idéia do que sejam.

Eu programo por hobby e estou fazendo um pequeno projeto pra um amigo, por favor me ajudem.
Não consigo saber o que fazer, tenho certeza que é algo simples mas pesquisei o dia todo e não encontrei a solução. O que passo no lugar desses parâmetros?.

Edit:
Essa é a parte em que uso o loop para chamar a procedure, cada vez que ela for chamada é um browser diferente usado.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
  for contagem := 1 to StrtoInt(Edit1.Text) do
  begin
browsers[contagem].OnDocumentComplete := nil;

NavigationOK := true;

browsers[contagem].OnDocumentComplete := DocCompleteA;
browsers[contagem].Navigate
  ('http://****/index.php?id=entrar');
end;
end;
```

Criação dos browsers:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for contagem := 1 to StrToInt(Edit1.Text) do
  begin
    campos[contagem] := TEdit.Create(self);
    campos[contagem].Parent := Form1;
    campos[contagem].Show;
    campos[contagem].Left := 150;
    campos[contagem].Top := 350;
    campos[contagem].Width := 600;
    browsers[contagem] := TWebBrowser.Create(Form1);
    TWinControl(browsers[contagem]).Parent := Form1;
    browsers[contagem].Align := alTop;
    browsers[contagem].Height := 300;
    browsers[contagem].Show;
    browsers[contagem].Silent := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Mas essa procedure é de algum evento de um componente?... se for poste aqui qual você está usando.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Sim, evento OnDocumentComplete de um WebBrowser, mas esse WebBrowser é criado em runtime, por isso preciso do loop. A procedure vai ser executada uma vez pra cada Browser criado

Comment: Como você está tratando esse loop, podes postar o código fonte na pergunta, assim ajudaria o pessoal do fórum a entender melhor e lhe ajudar. Abraços

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf alterei a pergunta com a parte em que chamo o loop com a procedure dentro. Se não for suficiente posso postar o código inteiro. Desculpe a bagunça na formatação mas eu sempre me bagunço nessa parte rsrs

Comment: para cada browser criado, você trata de um jeito diferente na função DocCompletaA?... ou é o mesmo para todos os browser criados. Se for assim, não é necessário passar uma variável de contagem como parâmetro, pois a cada laço ele executa o evento, entendeu?... qualquer coisa só falar

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Mesma tarefa para cada browser, o problema é que sem passar a variável ocorre um erro daqueles complicados de saber (rsrs), "violation 0x00000" <- parecido com isso. Colocando o número manualmente(browsers[1]...) faz o erro parar, o que me fez presumir que o erro está sendo na variável que não está sendo passada

Comment: Tem como fazer exatamente oque você está pedindo, mas eu acho que teria uma solução menos radical para o seu problema. Para fazer oque você esta pedindo, basta criar uma classe herdando de TWebBrowser, e sobrescrever a property que recebe o método OnDocumentComplete adicionado o seu novo parâmetro. Se não conseguir resolver o problema, podemos tentar esta solução.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iCont,iContagem: Integer;      
begin
  iCont := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  for iContagem := 0 to iCont-1 do
  begin
    browsers[iContagem].OnDocumentComplete := nil;
    NavigationOK := true;
    browsers[iContagem].OnDocumentComplete := DocCompleteA;
    browsers[iContagem].Navigate
    ('http://****/index.php?id=entrar');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Access violation at address 005E9DFF in module... se eu passar o valor manualmente dá certo, o que ta me levando a crer que o problema é em passar mesmo a variável

Comment: Como tais criando os browsers em runtime?

Comment: Tenho um botão para isso. O "cliente" quer escolher o tanto de browsers simultaneos. O botão simplesmente cria os browsers.

Comment: Podes postar na pergunta, como tais criando isso em modo de execução.

Comment: Já está lá amigo

Comment: Vou ter que montar algo parecido com o que você está falando, para ter uma ideia.

Comment: Posso colocar todo o código no pastebin caso desejar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48206/discussion-between-marciel-fonseca-and-jefferson-rudolf).

Answer (score 0):

Prezado,
O Sender é a referência do objeto que está realizando a requisição ao método, nesse caso é o próprio TWebBrowser.

```
procedure TForm1.OnDocumentComplete(
  Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch;
  var URL: OleVariant);
var
  currentBrowser: IWebBrowser;
  topBrowser: IWebBrowser;
  document: OleVariant;
  windowName: string;
begin
  currentBrowser := pDisp as IWebBrowser;
  topBrowser := (Sender as TWebBrowser).DefaultInterface;
  if currentBrowser = topBrowser then
  begin
     ShowMessage('Browser que completou:' tag:'+IntToStr(TWebBrowser(Sender).tag));
  end
  else
  begin
    document := currentBrowser.Document;
    windowName := document.ParentWindow.Name;
    //ShowMessage(Format('Frame "%s" was loaded', [windowName]));
  end;
end;
```

Observe a propriedade `TAG` na criação dos webs browsers:

```
procedure TForm1.BotaoCriaBrowsersClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for contagem := 0 to StrToInt(Edit1.Text)-1 do
  begin
    browsers[contagem] := TWebBrowser.Create(Form1);
    TWinControl(browsers[contagem]).Parent := Form1;
    browsers[contagem].Align := alTop;
    browsers[contagem].Height := 100;
    browsers[contagem].Tag := contagem;
    browsers[contagem].OnDocumentComplete:= Form1.OnDocumentComplete;
  end;
end;
```

Principais linhas para entendimento do exemplo:

> ```
> browsers[contagem].Tag := contagem;
> browsers[contagem].OnDocumentComplete:= Form1.OnDocumentComplete;
> ```

Dessa forma usei a propriedade `tag` para armazenar a posição do browser no `array`.

Sugestão para ver mais sobre TWebBrowser:

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_oleobject.htm